# Querying mongoTemplate using date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to find all rows before a certain date using `mongoTemplate` in Spring Java. This is returning no rows though there are lots of old records.

What is the problem?

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -73);
Date prevDate = cal.getTime();
List<AuditTrailDTO> dt = mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("AUDIT_CREATE_DATETIME").lte(prevDate)), AuditTrailDTO.class);
```

`AUDIT_CREATE_DATETIME` in Mongo DB is stored in this format:

```
Audit_Create_DateTime:2019-07-10 08:47:02.078
```

Comment: Is `Audit_Create_DateTime` of type `Date` ? Or a raw `String` ? It should work with `Date` type...

Answer (score 0):

It should work if the type of `Audit_Create_DateTime` is `Date`, so I assume `Audit_Create_DateTime` is of `String` type.

You can do the following to do a `less-than-equals` logic on a `String` field;

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");  
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("AUDIT_CREATE_DATETIME").lte(dateFormat.format(prevDate)));
List<AuditTrailDTO> dt = mongoTemplate.find(query, Customer.class);
```

which will return proper results, though I recommend properly storing `Date` values as correct type rather than in `String` type.

Comment: The audit date time is date type in mongo dB . So not sure why it is not working

Comment: @Sri the format looks non-date though, it ought to have some timezone value at the end I think. Mine has a `Z` at the end, can you confirm that the type is date? Check the schema of the document. Otherwise your `prevDate` might be invalid somehow.

Comment: @Sri can you add the schema of the document in your question? It would help a lot!

Comment: the Audit date time does have type Date when i look  in the schema,Can someone paste me a sample code please where using mongoTemplate i can find all records where the AuditDatetime( field type in mongoDb is Date) is less than or equal to a certain date example (July 22,2019)

Comment: @Sri they way you are finding with `.lte()` is correct. I tested on my local with `Date` field in Mongo, works perfectly. If the `Audit_Create_DateTime` is of `Date` type then the only problem must be that the `prevDate` you are using is wrong. Can you log `prevDate` value, are you sure it has the correct value?